# Installing libs faster

Tags: command-line, libraries, cache

(previously) I'm newbie at Ubuntu, so I'm installing wine fallowing the instructions to build biarch (does not know very well what is) from https://wiki.winehq.org/BuildingBiarchWineOnUbuntu and everything is going fine, but I got at point `bash configure --enable-win64` and wine instructions recommends to:

"If the configure or make steps fail then check the config.log file to make sure there aren't any missing build dependencies. If you can't figure it out then ask on the forum or IRC. "

and in my terminal I coincidently got:

```
configure: libGLU development files not found, GLU won't be supported.
configure: libOSMesa development files not found (or too old), OpenGL rendering in bitmaps won't be supported.
configure: OpenCL development files not found, OpenCL won't be supported.
configure: libdbus development files not found, no dynamic device support.
configure: libgnutls development files not found, no schannel support.
configure: lib(n)curses development files not found, curses won't be supported.
configure: libsane development files not found, scanners won't be supported.
configure: libv4l development files not found.
configure: libgphoto2 development files not found, digital cameras won't be supported.
configure: libgphoto2_port development files not found, digital cameras won't be auto-detected.
configure: liblcms development files not found, Color Management won't be supported.
configure: gstreamer-0.10 base plugins development files not found, gstreamer support disabled
configure: OSS sound system found but too old (OSSv4 needed), OSS won't be supported.
configure: libcapi20 development files not found, ISDN won't be supported.
configure: libcups development files not found, CUPS won't be supported.
configure: libgsm development files not found, gsm 06.10 codec won't be supported.
configure: libtiff development files not found, TIFF won't be supported.
configure: libmpg123 development files not found (or too old), mp3 codec won't be supported.
configure: libopenal development files not found (or too old), OpenAL won't be supported.
configure: libldap (OpenLDAP) development files not found, LDAP won't be supported.
configure: WARNING: prelink not found, base address of core dlls won't be set correctly.
configure: WARNING: No OpenGL library found on this system. OpenGL and Direct3D won't be supported.
configure: WARNING: libxml2 development files not found (or too old), XML won't be supported.
configure: WARNING: libxslt development files not found, xslt won't be supported.
configure: Finished.  Do 'make' to compile Wine.
```

Lots of libs to update, so I searched and I'm updating like this:

```
apt-cache search <lib-dev>
```

so if I got a positive feedback, I install using:

```
apt-get install <lib feedback name>
```

But using this method for all this method will take time, how can I install all this lib faster? (sorry for long text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install multiple libraries with one command:

```
apt install lib1 lib2 lib3
```

To avoid `apt-cache search` you can just type the beginning of a library's name into `apt install` command and press <kbd>TAB</kbd> to autocomplete.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It worked well, by the way what's the difference of apt-get install and your apt install (that worked with me), and how will I install OSS sound system and  gstreamer plugins? like libs?

Comment: @LucasTrentini `apt-get` is used on older Ubuntu versions, `apt install` is the current way. Can't answer the other questions now because I'm not on Ubuntu while typing this.

Comment: don't need to,I got apt manual  man apt-get